# How to show context menu when right-click released?

Tags: 10.04, menu

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04.

**When I right-click, menu popup too quickly, and the first menu item is clicked.**

If I right-click in desktop, it create a new folder sometime.

If I right-click in terminal, it open a new terminal sometime.

...

Is there some way to delay context menu?

Or how can I offset context menu a little bit pixels to the right-bottom direction? (like firefox)

Or how can I config Gnome to popup menu when right-mouse **released**? (like windows xp)

Comment: could you change the mouse? or if you are using a laptop, plug in a mouse; what happens with the new mouse?

Comment: definitely,change the mouse i happen to have the same issue as you,but lucky for me i have 2 mouse or do what i do, when you right.click hold the mouse button so you can put the cursor away from the menu.

Comment: This is an issue I've been experiencing recently too. I think it only happens if the mouse is moved during the right click (but it only needs to be moved very very slightly). For me the logical workaround would be to stop rightclicks on menus from activating the menus

Comment: I can not answer our three questions. But I think you should just change the way you use the context-menu: Try to right-click-&-hold, then select the menu-item you want to and release the right-click on it. That is much easier than changing the menu-behavior. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug:

- [Bug report in Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+2.0/+bug/410636) - unfortunately only a wishlist bug. :-(
- [Upstream bug report](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=591258) - more information, no consensus reached yet (means: wait or contribute).